# Why won't slime spawn in my slime chunk in the ocean?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I dug out a slime chunk in between Y levels **24-28**. I lit the room very well and a single hostile mob hasn't spawned in the room. The room is **7** blocks tall. It's about **5** chunks away from land to avoid hostile mobs spawning in nearby caves preventing the slime from spawning. I triple checked the coordinates and everything to make sure I was in a slime chunk. My slime chunk coordinates are **536,309** (x,z) and my seed is 8857034577360149641 if that helps with anything. Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: How much time have you waited for things to spawn?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure there's solid ground, when the **light level is 5 and below** it will spawn.
In 1.18 Caves and Cliffs, **you need a light level of 0**.
If the platform did not work try making it underground, because the system thinks it's still an ocean and can't spawn slime or it will drown.

If nothing works, lower down your chunks and stay 30 block away.

Comment: I sincerely don't see how this is the answer. Slimes spawn in all light levels, and if the room is free of water, the game won't "think it's still an ocean".

Comment: The chunk is under the ocean floor. So no water. And slimes can spawn at any light level. And I went about 80-90 blocks away from the slime farm and I came back and no slime.

Comment: the biome like if its at deep ocean biome the biome will be that.